# Examining the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x_1,x_2) = 4x_1^2+x_2^2$ for uniform convexity.

Tags: convex-analysis

A quick question from a multiple choice test I am preparing for:

> Is the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x_1,x_2) = 4x_1^2+x_2^2$ [uniformly convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Uniformly_convex_functions)?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake I am working on an edit.

Comment: I finished my edit, it should be alright now.

Comment: I get hat the left hand side is $3(x_1-y_1)^2 + \|x-y\|^2$ which is the same as you just with $+x_2^2$ and $-2x_2y_2$. Check your signs.

Comment: You are right I corrected the signs.

Comment: The conclusion is still wrong. Is the left hand side negative for this choice of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Ahhhh, no it is not...

Comment: Can I find such a $\mu$ at all?

Comment: AHHH, we can use a different criterion that makes it much much easier. I edited my post.

Comment: You already had the answer if you just factored the left hand side of what you got. A hint has already been given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to remember the fact that

> $f$ is uniformly convex (on $X$) iff there is a $\mu > 0$ such that $$d^T \nabla^2(y)d \ge \mu \|d\|^2$$ for all $x \in X$ and all $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

This is easy to check.